# viewDidLoad is called only the first time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

Maybe someone could tell me why when launch my app in the second time (after pressing the home button) the method `viewDidLoad:` is not being called?

Comment: Can we have some code please to illustrate this problem (e.g. with an NSLog(@"viewDidLoad"); in the relevant place which you have tested and made sure does not work as expected?

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 4 apps are no longer exited when pressing the home button. They are moved out of RAM, paused and then continued when you re-enter them, not launched again.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS4 there is:

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application { }

Which is called when the application becomes active (out of background) you could call things from here that need to happen when you open the app.

Thanks
James

Comment: There is also 

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Answer (score 0):

The second time you "launch" your application, in fact you are not launching but only re-activating (your application was in background). Your views are not reloaded.

As said in the previous answers :

- You can detect it via `(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` and execute some code here (refresh HMI, refetch datas, etc...),
- Or move your code to `viewWillAppear`