# iOS Simulator fails every time after building and starting app second time. How to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, appcode

I've started to learn iOS development. And I use AppCode and Swift. After starting AppCode first time everything is OK. But when I try to build and start project again this window appears:

[image]

And then project is successfully built and this message appears in the simulator log:

com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[1181]: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=PackagePatchFailed, ErrorDescription=Could not hardlink copy /Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/037261F9-6926-4755-AD40-08C0D88B8703/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/95BECC1C-DE32-4529-9BFC-81F3C97AB1A6/Test.app to /Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/037261F9-6926-4755-AD40-08C0D88B8703/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.pRI2uY/extracted/Payload/Test.app with manifest /Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/037261F9-6926-4755-AD40-08C0D88B8703/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.pRI2uY/extracted/com.apple.deltainstallcommands.Pizdaxui.Test}

If found the solution: 
I should run Simulator -> Reset Contents And Settings. But It's really annoying to do this every time. Is there any other solution to fix this?

Comment: stop the project and run again

Comment: the dialogs box says to stop running process and run this application again. Please check and `stop Session and run` press to run updated code application...

Comment: Yes I've already done it. But the question is how to fix LaunchServicesError. I posted this dialog screenshot to clarify what is going on

Comment: Reinstall xcode Or check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586416/viewdidload-is-called-only-the-first-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586416/viewdidload-is-called-only-the-first-time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Comment: From the duplicate which describes LaunchServicesError error 0, If you need more specific help, please provide the entirety of the error message from CoreSimulator.log and any messages from installd and CoreSimulatorBridge that appear around the same time in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[Device UDID]/system.log as that will reveal the underlying problem.

Answer (score -5):

I think you should try Xcode, which is the official IDF for making applications for Apple.

Or you could fix it by restarting your IDE.

Comment: Most AppCode `errors` stem from some eXcode disfunction in my experience.

Comment: I see,
Try to quit simulator and try again.